# How to fix 'get value' in ControlValueAccessor

Tags: angular

I have a custom component (ControlValueAccessor). Inside this component, when (focusout) I try to get "this.value", but it gives me the old value, what's the problem?

It's my date.component.ts

```
export const CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => DateComponent),
  multi: true
};

@Component({
  selector: 'app-date',
  templateUrl: './date.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./date.component.css'],
  providers: [
    CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR
  ],
})
export class DateComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

  value: any;
  onChange: any = () => { };
  onTouched: any = () => { };
  disabled: boolean;

  NormalizedDate(): void {
    console.log(this.value); // here I want to get the value,and expect to get value from "formControlName", but it doesn't work
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.disabled = isDisabled;
  }

  writeValue(obj: any): void {
    this.value = obj ? obj : '';
    this.onChange(obj);
  }

}
```

date.component.html

```
<mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>{{label}}</mat-label>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [value]="value" [disabled]="disabled"
         (dateChange)="onChange($event.target.value)"
         (blur)="onTouched()"
         (focusout)="NormalizedDate()"
  >
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

app.component.ts (This is where my custom component is rendered.)

```
<div class="col-md-4">
          <app-date formControlName="createDate"></app-date>
        <h1>{{form.controls.createDate.value}}</h1>
      </div>
```

Comment: Doesn't the added answer solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is because `value` has got a one way property binding i.e. `[value]="value"`, changes in the view will not change the content of the variable `value`. If you want to get the current value use, `normalizedDate($event.target.value)`

```
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [value]="value" [disabled]="disabled"
     (dateChange)="onChange($event.target.value)"
     (blur)="onTouched()"
     (focusout)="normalizedDate($event.target.value)">


  normalizedDate(val): void {
     console.log(val);
  }
```

See an example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/controlvalueaccessorgeneric-4rabaq?file=src/app/app.component.ts